# How can I update a .properties file using FinalBuilder?

Tags: configuration-files, finalbuilder

There is a .properties file containing many name-value pairs, separated by "=". Is there any standard way in FinalBuilder to update the value of some properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by using "Text Find/Replace" action and its wildcard feature. Just replace:

```
 <propertyname>=*
```

with

```
 <propertyname>=<YourDesiredProperty>
```